# CMultiFileUpload didn't work in CJuiDialog widget Yii

Tags: yii, cjuidialog, cmultifileupload

Am using CJuiDialog widget with ajaxlink for popup form..it works well..

But now i need to upload multiple files from that popup form.. so i use CMultiFileUpload for upload option but i acts like a normal single file button.. please help me to solve this.. Here is my Code:

```
 <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(Yii::t('image','Upload'),array('gallery/create'),array(
    'success'=>'js:function(data){
    $("#gallery-form").dialog("open");
    document.getElementById("add_images").innerHTML=data;}'));
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
            'id'=>'gallery-form',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>Yii::t('image','Upload'),
                'autoOpen'=>false,
                'model'=>'true',
                'width'=>'auto',
                'height'=>'auto',
            ),
            ));
echo "<div id='add_images'></div>";
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');  ?>
```

and this is my controller action:

```
            if(isset($_FILES['image']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Photo'];
        $images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image');
        if(isset($images) && count($images)> 0) 
        {
            foreach ($images as $image=>$pic) 
            {
                               if (!is_dir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/gallery/'.$user->username===true) ){
                                   mkdir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/gallery/'.$user->username, 0777);
            }


                            if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/gallery/'.$user->username.'/'.$pic->name))    
                {   
                    $model->setIsNewRecord(true);
                    $model->id = null;
                                $model->image = $pic->name;
                                            $model->setAttribute('user_id',$id);
                                $model->save();
                }               
            }
                    $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }
 Ajax Popup Request
                if( Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest )
                             {
                    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
                    $this->renderPartial('create',array(
                                        'model'=>$model,
                                ));}else{}
```

This is my rendered partial view file which works fine with multiupload file without call with cjuidialog but when i call it with cjuidialog it just support only single file upload..Please help.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'gallery-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
 'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',),
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image'); ?>
     <?php
      $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
         'model'=>$model,
         'name'=>'image',
         'attribute'=>'image',
         'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png',

      ));
    ?>

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'image'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Upload' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renderPartial doesn't load scripts by default and the CMultiFileUpload widget uses scripts, so you need to make the renderPartial load scripts. You can do that by changing your renderPartial to include two extra parameters:

```
$this->renderPartial('viewName', 
    array('variable' => $variable), false, true
);
```

Notice the `false, true` added to the end? The false means "don't return the view, display it" and the true means "postprocess," which is what will add the scripts.

For more info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail

[edit]

Here's a different way of loading the dialog. It still requires the "false, true" in renderPartial:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('uploadDialog', "
$(function(){
    $('#upload-image').click(function(){
        $('#gallery-form').load('".Yii::app()->createUrl('gallery/create')."', function(){
            $('#gallery-form').dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
});");

echo CHtml::link('Upload', '#', array('id' => 'upload-image'));

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    'id'=>'gallery-form',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>Yii::t('image','Upload'),
        'autoOpen'=>false,
        'model'=>'true',
        'width'=>'auto',
        'height'=>'auto',
    ),
));

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
```

Then, remove the line below from your controller:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
```

If that still doesn't work, I would recommend adding your renderPartial directly in between the CJuiDialog widget tags instead of loading the content via ajax.

Comment: You might have figured it out by now (I think we are in very different timezones) but I posted a different method for you to try if not. It still loads the dialog content via ajax, just using a click event instead of ajaxLink. I have tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: found a small bug in above solution.If i close the JuiDialoge and reopen the dialog then this occurs..`TypeError: $.fn.MultiFile.intercepted[method] is undefined

value = $.fn.MultiFile.intercepted[method].apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you a step. You also need to remove the line: Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false; from your controller.

Comment: Now this what i call perfect solution. Thanks a lot frosty :)